# Image angle changes depending position of mouse

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Im trying to build a game where enemies jump out of the water and you fire water at them...

When the user clicks to fire I want the img src to point in the direction of the click, to achieve what I have so far I have css and js script (code below) however it looks to static, I feel having the water point in the direction of the users input would help a lot however Im not sure how to achieve this?

```
 //bind to gun events
        this.playfield.on('gun:out_of_ammo',_.bind(function(){this.outOfAmmo();},this));
        this.playfield.on('gun:fire',_.bind(function(){
            this.flashScreen();
        },this));
```

...

```
 flashScreen : function(){
        $(".theFlash").css("display","block");
        setTimeout(function(){
            $('.theFlash').css("display","none");
        },400);
    }
```

CSS

```
.theFlash{
    background-color : transparent;
    width:900px;
    height:500px;
    position:relative;
    margin:0 auto;  
    z-index:10;
    display:none;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I put together an example below that will hopefully help you out.

You just have to specify the source from where the shoot is fired (`sourceX`,`sourceY`), calculate the angle to where the mouse is clicked (done below, so should just be to copy/paste) and adjust the `transform: rotate(Xdeg);` to the new angle.

Make sure to set the orgin in css with `transform-origin`, so that the flame rotates around the source and not the flame itself.

Try it out at the bottom.

```js
var game,
    flame,
    sourceX = 310,
    sourceY = 110;

window.onload = function() {
  game = document.getElementById('game');
  flame = document.getElementById('flame');
  game.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
      var targetX = e.pageX,
       targetY = e.pageY,
          deltaX = targetX - sourceX,
          deltaY = targetY - sourceY,
          rad = Math.atan2(deltaY, deltaX),
          deg = rad * (180 / Math.PI),
          length = Math.sqrt(deltaX*deltaX+deltaY*deltaY);   
   
      fire(deg,length);
  }, false);
};

function fire(deg,length) {
    flame.style.opacity = 1;
    flame.style.transform = 'rotate(' + deg + 'deg)'
    flame.style.width = length + 'px';
    setTimeout(function() {
       flame.style.opacity = 0;
    },300);
};
```

```css
#game {
  position: relative;
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #666;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#source {
  border-radius: 50%;
  z-index: 101;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: #ff0000;
  position: absolute;
  left: 300px;
  top: 100px;
}

#flame {
  width: 300px;
  height: 3px;
  background-color: #00ff00;
  position: absolute;
  left: 310px;
  top: 110px;
  opacity: 0;
  transform-origin: 0px 0px;
  transform: rotate(180deg);
  transition: opacity .2s;
}
```

```html
<div id="game">
  <div id="source">

  </div>
  <div id="flame">

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Here you go https://jsfiddle.net/b77x4rq4/2/ . It was just that you have to change javascript settings in jsfiddle to nowrap for `window.onload` to work.

Comment: That is exactly what I want! I can get it working on its own however when implementing the code into the games script it stops working? Would you mind taking a look via pm?... Its really bugging me!

Comment: I'm not available for pm at the moment, but all the pieces should be there. I'm sure you'll figure it out :) Javascript console is your friend. Start from the beginning, add one step at the time and see what part makes it stop. You can probably not just copy/paste the code without some adjustments for your own game.

Comment: Hi I have been playing around with the code and got it now working within the game screen and also in the correct position there seems to be a slight problem with the 'laser line' though (it seems to also be that bit to short from where the user has clicked) I have updated the game here : http://mckenziedave.co.uk/client_files/html5_game/

Comment: Yeah, mouse position can be a pain sometimes. What you see is actually the mouse position (`e.pageX` and `e.pageY`) from the **edge of the screen**. Since you have a margin on your game screen, you have to subtract that from the x and y. This is probably out of the scope of this question, but there are a lot of questions on Stack Overflow that covers exact mouse positions (search for *mouse position relative to element javascript* or something like that). Here is a great article explaining it as well http://acko.net/blog/mouse-handling-and-absolute-positions-in-javascript/

Comment: I still cant get it working... is there any chance you could take a look?

Comment: It still seems to be off from where the user clicks?

Comment: If your link above is updated with the latest version, I still don't see that you take game window offset into account. I have updated the jsfiddle with comments to try to make it more clear. https://jsfiddle.net/3oesyqnr/2/

Comment: Sorry Im working offline on it the game screen is W:900px H:500px, I try adding it to the JS script (after the rect.left / rect.top) but now it doesnt show at all? Im not sure what I'm doing wrong?...

Comment: Hi Magnus, Im still having trouble with this... I dont understand how to subtract the from the edge of the screen... the latest version can be seen here http://mckenziedave.co.uk/client_files/html5_game/ any help would be greatful!

Comment: The window.onload on your page should probably look something like this. Can't test it locally though, so not sure if it works, but it should be in line with what you want to do. https://jsfiddle.net/a1o5jLx8/

Answer (score 0):

I would not recommend building games in this manner, Canvas and SVG are the preferred methods of building browser games, with that said it can be done.

Try this

https://jsfiddle.net/b77x4rq4/

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var middleOfElementTop = 250; // margin from top + half of height
    var middleOfElementLeft = 125; // margin from left + half of width

  $("#main").mousemove(function(e){
    var mouseX = e.offsetX;
    var mouseY = e.offsetY;

    var angle = Math.atan2(mouseY - middleOfElementTop, mouseX - middleOfElementLeft) * 180 / Math.PI;
    $(".box").css({"transform": "rotate(" + angle + "deg)"})


  })
});
```

Comment: Google managed to build an entire Pacman game that AFAIK just used divs.

Comment: I said I wouldn't recommend, didnt say it was wrong

Comment: @Alnitak Google's Pacman is actually Canvas, but it's the same principles if you use div's, svg or canvas, so either way is a good way to learn :) http://www.google.com/doodles/30th-anniversary-of-pac-man